# cumulative grouping

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, tidyverse, cumulative-sum

I have the following data frame:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,1,3,2,2), b=6:10)
##  a    b
##  1    6
##  1    7
##  3    3
##  2    9
##  2    10
```

I want to analyze the data by groups (a is the grouping parameter), but instead of the usual (e.g. each value specify a group of rows, and the groups are disjoint) I need "cumulative groups". that is, for the value of a=i, the group should contain all the rows in which a<=i. These are not disjoint groups, but still I want to summarize each group separately.

So for example, if for each group I want the mean of b, the result would be:

```
##    a    mean_b
##    1    6.5
##    2    8
##    3    7
```

note that in the real scenario behind this simplified example, I cannot analyze disjoint group separately and then aggregate the relevant groups. the summarize function must be "aware" of all the rows in that group to perform the computation.

So of course, I can use some apply functions and compute things in the good old way, and make a new df out of it, but I look for the dplyr/tidyverse like functions to do that.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 arrange(a) %>%
 group_by(a) %>%
 summarise(sum_b = sum(b)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(sum_b = cumsum(sum_b))

#     a sum_b
#  <dbl> <int>
#1    1.    13
#2    2.    32
#3    3.    40
```

We take `sum` by group (`a`) and then take cumulative sum adding the previous value of the group in the next group.

Comment: This would not work generally, because the initial summary is done for the small, disjoint groups, and then aggregate to the bigger group.  the actual summary function I'm going to use will not work that way

Comment: @amit This works for the example you have shown. It would be better if you could provide an example which represents your real data.

Comment: @amit well, in that case I'll do `df %>%
  arrange(a) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(sum_b = sum(b), 
            total = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(sum_b = cumsum(sum_b)/cumsum(total)) %>%
  select(-total)
` but I doubt even if this solves your actual problem.

Comment: ok. how to workaround - I know. I'm looking for a way to actually work with overlapping groups. if there is such a way.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look and I don't see how it is possible with `dplyr` itself. However, we can hack the `group_by` function to make it cumulative. I'll quickly walkd you through it:

First, I make your df. It doesn't really fit your output above, so I slightly changed it.

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,1,3,2,2), b=6:10)
df$b[3] <- 3
```

Now I use the normal `group_by` to check out what it actually does to the `data.frame`.

```
library(dplyr)
df_grouped <- df %>%
  arrange(a) %>%
  group_by(a)
> attributes(df_grouped)
$class
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

$row.names
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$names
[1] "a" "b"

$vars
[1] "a"

$drop
[1] TRUE

$indices
$indices[[1]]
[1] 0 1

$indices[[2]]
[1] 2 3

$indices[[3]]
[1] 4


$group_sizes
[1] 2 2 1

$biggest_group_size
[1] 2

$labels
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

So besides other things, there is a new attribute called `indices` where the group of each element in the grouped variable is referenced. We can actually just change that to make it cumulative.

```
for (i in seq_along(attributes(df_grouped)[["indices"]])[-1]) {
  attributes(df_grouped)[["indices"]][[i]] <- c(
    attributes(df_grouped)[["indices"]][[i - 1]],
    attributes(df_grouped)[["indices"]][[i]]
  )
}
```

It looks a bit weird but is straightforward. The elements of each group are added to the next group. E.g. all elements from group 1 are added to group 2.

```
> attributes(df_grouped)$indices
[[1]]
[1] 0 1

[[2]]
[1] 0 1 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 0 1 3 4 2
```

We can use the changed groups in the normal `dplyr` way.

```
> df_grouped %>%
+   summarise(sum_b = mean(b))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a sum_b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   6.5
2     2   8  
3     3   7
```

Now of course this is pretty ugly and looks very hacky. But inside a function that doesn't really matter as long as it is still efficient (which it is). So let's make a custom `group_by`.

```
group_by_cuml <- function(.data, ...) {
  .data_grouped <- group_by(.data, ...)
  for (i in seq_along(attributes(.data_grouped)[["indices"]])[-1]) {
    attributes(.data_grouped)[["indices"]][[i]] <- c(
      attributes(.data_grouped)[["indices"]][[i - 1]],
      attributes(.data_grouped)[["indices"]][[i]]
    )
  }
  return(.data_grouped)
}
```

Now you can use the custom function in clean `dplyr` pipe.

```
> df %>%
+   group_by_cuml(a) %>% 
+   summarise(sum_b = mean(b))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a sum_b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   6.5
2     2   8  
3     3   7
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way :

```
df %>% 
  arrange(a) %>%
  map_dfr(seq_along(as <- unique(.$a)),
          ~filter(.y, a %in% as[1:.]),.y = ., .id = "a") %>%
  group_by(a = meta_group) %>%
  summarise(b = mean(b))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# a     b
# <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1   6.5
# 2     2   7.0
# 3     3   8.0
```

If you want a separate function you can do :

```
summarize2 <- function(.data, ..., .by){
  grps <- select_at(.data,.by) %>% pull %>% unique
  .data %>%
    arrange_at(.by) %>%
    map_dfr(seq_along(grps),
             ~ filter_at(.y, .by,all_vars(. %in% grps[1:.x])),
             .y = .,
             .id = "meta_group") %>%
    group_by(meta_group) %>%
    summarise(...)
}

df %>% 
  summarize2(b = mean(b), .by = "a")
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   meta_group     b
#        <chr> <dbl>
# 1          1   6.5
# 2          2   7.0
# 3          3   8.0

df %>% 
  summarize2(b = mean(b), .by = vars(a))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   meta_group     b
#        <chr> <dbl>
# 1          1   6.5
# 2          2   7.0
# 3          3   8.0
```

Comment: What about cummulative grouping by more than one column to facet the plot? Could you provide a workaround?

Comment: I am not sure what would be the expected output, it seems quite different in any case. I'd suggest a different question with sample input and expected input and if you ping me here I'll be happy to take a look

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the base function `Reduce` with the argument `accumulate = TRUE`. Once you concatenate, then you can apply any function, i.e.

```
Reduce(c, split(df$b,df$a), accumulate = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] 6 7

#[[2]]
#[1]  6  7  9 10

#[[3]]
#[1]  6  7  9 10  3
```

and then for the mean,

```
sapply(Reduce(c, split(df$b,df$a), accumulate = TRUE), mean)
[1] 6.5 8.0 7.0
```